# SQL Server INNER JOIN with two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB` like this:

`TableA`

```
ItemCode |Qty    |BarCode       |Brand
AC       |2      |123           |BRO       
AB       |2      |1234          |BRO       
AD       |2      |1234          |BRO
```

`TableB`

```
ItemCode |Brand  |BarCode       |Qty
AC       |BRO    |123           |1
AB       |BRO    |1234          |2
```

I trying to get the result like Records `TableA` not equal to Qty of `TableB` and records in `TableA` is not in `TbleB`

The query I have tried is

```
SELECT 
    A.ItemCode AS ItmA, B.ItemCode AS ItmB, A.Qty AS AQty, B.Qty AS BQty 
FROM 
    TableA A 
INNER JOIN  
    TableB B ON A.Brand = B.Brand 
WHERE 
    (A.Qty <> B.Qty)
    AND A.ItemCode NOT IN (B.ItemCode)
```

I am getting result like this

```
ItmA   |ItmB   |AQty   |BQty
--------------------------------
AB     | AC    |  2    |  1
AD     | AC    |  2    |  1
```

But I am trying to get the result with ItemCode `AC` AND `AD`

Comment: I hope you realize that aside from the order of columns, the structure of the tables are identical.  In general, that is a huge no-no in database design.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get records from `TableA` that are not in `TableB`, then think `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.ItemCode AS ItmA,B.ItemCode AS ItmB,A.Qty AS AQty,B.Qty AS BQty
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN
     TableB B
     ON A.Brand = B.Brand
WHERE A.Qty <> B.Qty OR B.Brand IS NULL;
```

The rest is just applying the logic of your query.

You can also express this as:

```
SELECT A.ItemCode AS ItmA,B.ItemCode AS ItmB,A.Qty AS AQty,B.Qty AS BQty
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN
     TableB B
     ON A.Brand = B.Brand AND A.Qty = B.Qty 
WHERE B.Brand IS NULL;
```

But I think the first version comes close to how you expressed the rules.